# C# label is not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, list, class, collections, label

I'm creating a registration app where you can enter the student name, id and gpa and it will all be stored in a collection list. The label is showing as 0 even when students are registered. Here is the relevant code. Any help is appreciated.

```
namespace Lab09
{
class Student
{
    string name;
    int id;
    int intNumber;
    decimal gpa;

    public Student(string Name, int Id, decimal Gpa)
    {
        name = Name;
        id = Id;
        gpa = Gpa;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        set { name = value; }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
    public int Id
    {

        get
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
    public decimal Gpa
    {

        get
        {
            return gpa;
        }
    }
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return intNumber;
        }
    }
}
}


namespace Lab09
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Student> listofStudents;
    int intCurrentStudent = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listofStudents = new List<Student>();
    }

private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Decimal.Parse(txtGPA.Text) > 0 && Decimal.Parse(txtGPA.Text) <= 4)
            {
                if (txtName.Text != "")
                {
                    listofStudents.Add(new Student(txtName.Text, Int32.Parse(txtID.Text), Decimal.Parse(txtGPA.Text)));
                    intCurrentStudent = listofStudents.Count - 1;
                    txtName.Enabled = false;
                    txtID.Enabled = false;
                    txtGPA.Enabled = false;
                    btnRegister.Enabled = false;
                    if (listofStudents.Count > 1)
                    {
                        btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    displayNumStudents();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a name and GPA must be above 0 and less than or equal to 4");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ID and GPA need to be numbers");
        }
    }

    private void displayNumStudents()
    {
        int NumOfStudents = 0;
        foreach (Student aStudent in listofStudents)
        {
            NumOfStudents += aStudent.Number;
        }
        lblNum.Text = NumOfStudents.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Your `Student.Number` never set and have its default value 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have field `int intNumber` that your `Number` property is returning, but you aren't ever setting it.  And then you're using that number to count your students, which doesn't make sense.

I assume you want the registered student count:

```
private void displayNumStudents()
{
    int NumOfStudents = listOfStudents.Count();
    lblNum.Text = NumOfStudents.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `intNumber;`
In your student class is never assigned and only returned via the `Number` property in your `Student` class.

```
public int Number
{
    get
    {
        return intNumber;
    }
}
```

You need to update this property when a new Student is added to the collection.

You could modify your `Student` constructor to take in this argument and assign it there:

```
 public Student(string Name, int Id, decimal Gpa, int studentNumber)
 {
        name = Name;
        id = Id;
        gpa = Gpa;
        intNumber = studentNumber;
 }
```

You would then have to pass this to the new `Student` object when you create it and then add it to the list, for example:

```
 string name = txtName.Text;
 int id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
 decimal gpa = decimal.Parse(txtGPA.Text);
 int studentNumber = listofStudents.Count() + 1;

 Student student = new Student(name, id, gpa, studentNumber);

 listofStudents.Add(student);
```